# PHP Create new array per row of MYSQL Info, and store the arrays in a array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Don't ask me why I need it, I've tried to find it on the web and have failed. 
I need it to find rows of info on my database and per row it creates a array with one row and stores that array in an array and carries on with the rest of the rows.

I will then generate a new word doc per array found in the array of arrays( I can do this myself.)
I'm sorry I don't make much sense, I don't really know how to explain this...

Comment: I looks pretty straightforward unless I am missing something. What specifically is a problem for you?

Comment: That's common practice I'd say. Have a look at the documentation for a start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
$query = mysql_query($query, $connection);

$rows = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}

// You now have an array of your DB rows in $rows

foreach ($rows as $row) {
  createWordDoc($row);
}
```

If you don't actually need to cache the rows you could do this directly in your first loop of course:

```
$rows = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  createWordDoc($row);
}
```